# nitrogen console Segmentation fault(core dumped)

Tags: erlang, nitrogen

I download nitrogen in http://nitrogenproject.com/downloads, and what I download is nitrogen-2.3.1-mochiweb.tar.gz, a linux binares.
When I run ./bin/nitrogen console ，it's error  "/lib64/libc.so.6:version`GLIBC2.14`" not found. And after I installed glibc-2.14 and glibc 2.15,I run ./bin/nitrogen console again, but it failed,and the error is **"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"**.

I have no idea about this problem.I check the ./log/run_erl.log, but found nothing useful.

Comment: I had found a more serious problem, after I install glibc_2.14 and glibc_2.15,and run export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib:/opt/glibc-2.15/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH in linux shell,not just nitrogen cannot start,the vim can not start too.When I use vim to open a file,it just "Segmentation fault" too. I think the problem is glibc, maybe I install it in a wrong way.

Comment: I have change the way to install nitrogen. I download the source code and compile it success.Now it's runing well.By the way, I think this problem should be closed but I do not know how to close it .